# What is the advantage of using Dunn index over other metrics for evaluating clustering algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, clustering, unsupervised-learning, model-evaluations

There are many metrics to evaluate clustering algorithm like Calinski-Harabaz Index, Dunn index, Rand index, etc. Are there any advantage of using Dunn index over other metrics for evaluating clustering algorithm (K-means in particular)? If yes, what are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will often give the same preferences.

Do not forget that these are largely **heuristics**. They won't have much advantages over one another. That is why there are so many.

As a guideline, look at the definitions. Choose that index, whose equation is most relevant for your problem. (Yes, you *do* need to understand what they do. Clustering is hard, it is easy to get meaningless results by just looking at the code and scores and forgetting the underlying math.)